# Sharepoint 2007 - People and Groups - Add Separate Editable 'Notes' Column

Tags: permissions

Is it possible to add a column to a List of People/Groups that is basically a 'Notes' column which isn't attached to their Active Directory data (and is editable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand you correctly, buy here is my take

Create a new Custom List with 2 columns:

1. Entity (Person/Group)
2. Notes (Multiple lines of text)

if you actually want to modify the TYPE "Person/Group" to give you a Notes option out of the display options, you would need to still create the list above, create a custom field in visual studio, inherit the people/group field and add the Note coming from that list.

Comment: This is good, but it doesn't bring in the list of users in a specified group. Any idea how to go about that?

Comment: Ok apparently this is the only way to do it. I cannot find a possible way to add a custom column to a group.